# Как подключить через Samba, если есть юзер, пароль и домен (или группа)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, samba

Как подключить через Samba. Есть юзер, пароль и домен (или группа). Samba тоже стоит в Ubuntu. Но не команды, вроде `mount -t smbfs`, которые находил, не работают.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте выполнить два шага:

1. Что бы мой samba-клиент увидел виндовозную сеть, нужно в /etc/samba/smb.conf прописать wins-сервер:

   workgroup = MSHOME

   wins server = 192.168.0.1
2. Монтируем SAMBA шару

   mount -t cifs //192.168.0.1/share /mnt/share -o username=LOGIN,password=PASSWORD,iocharset=utf8,codepage=866,ro

Понятно, что IP, название шары, логин и пароль - надо Вам поправить.